# How does custom user URLs work?

Tags: url-rewriting, url-routing, social-networking

Today, I'm asking a question out of curiosity.

The new sites, I'm talking about.. Tumblr, Pinterest and many more are giving their users custom URLs to their sites, for example, mine on Tumblr would be maurocasas.tumblr.com instead of tumblr.com/maurocasas, as Facebook does.

My question is how do you handle this URLs? I'm curious. Some sites also let you point your own domain to your blog/site, so I could direct maurocasas.com to my Tumblr.

How do they do this? I'm curious.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple, as long as you have control over the DNS configuration of your domain. Just set up a wildcard subdomain pointing to your webserver, and then just parse the subdomain part of the hostname of the incoming request and  use it as the username. You might have to configure your webserver as well to support it.

Comment: I honestly thought it was a much harder process. Haha, Thanks for the response!